# Collecting specific data from a website using cURL(php)

Tags: php, html, parsing, curl

I am working on a website, and part of it allows users to review products. I am hoping to achieve a simple goal which is to list out the products and say "No reviews yet!"

Since products are always being made I would like to automatically collect the names, prices, and maybe a picture...

I currently am trying to access this information from [HERE](http://www.nrs.com/category/2740/whitewater-kayaking/womens-life-jackets)
and here is my current code :

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://www.nrs.com/category/2740/whitewater-kayaking/womens-life-    jackets");
$fp = fopen("collected.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

It collects the data in a text file.
Here are a couple of issues when trying to parse the html.
    - First, I need to make sure all the pagination is full, or loop through pages.
    - I need to collect the names of the products etc... So, cutting out certain code
until I am left with only the information I want
    - Have it write out a seperator like |*| so when my website displays the name it knows when to write out the next products.
    - Make it difficult for the website owner to block this... I am hoping he keeps the div names, etc... the same.
    - Stop searching once no more can be found

Here is the code I think is important on their website :

```
<div class="categoryItem">
    <div class="shortDesc">
    <p>The beautifully designed Astral Linda women's life jacket is affordable, lightweight and all-day comfortable for any type of boating. The thin back works comfortably with any kayak or raft seat.</p>
    </div>
    <a href="/product/40086.02/astral-womens-linda-pfd" data-prodImg="40086.02"><img   class="productImageThumb"   src="http://nrsweb5.richfx.com.edgesuite.net/image/media/40086_02_Azul_Front_010313_150x150.jpg" width="150" height="150" ALT="Astral Women&#39;s Linda PFD" /></a>
        <div class="productColorOptions">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Azul"><img src="http://nrsweb5.richfx.com.edgesuite.net/image/media/40086_02_Azul_Front_010313_swatch_15x15.jpg" alt="" border="0"></a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Gray"><img  src="http://nrsweb5.richfx.com.edgesuite.net/image/media/40086_02_Gray_Front_010313_swatch_ 15x15.jpg" alt="" border="0"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="clearIt"></div>
   <h2><a href="/product/40086.02/astral-womens-linda-pfd">Astral Women's Linda PFD</a> </h2>
   <p class="reviewLinkBlock"></p>
   <h4>$94.95</h4>
   <div class="compareButton"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-compare="40086.02"   rel="nofollow" class="compareBtn compareAdd">Compare</a><span class="cancelCompare"><a    href="javascript:void(0);" data-compare="40086.02" rel="nofollow"    class="compareRemove">x</a></span></div>
</div><!-- end class="categoryItem" -->
```

There are multiple categoryItem divs and are only specifically for the products. The user even nicely commented it. So now I need to keep peeling away layers of code until I can reach the name... Any suggestions/solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using regular expressions to match elements containing the information you need, using preg_match_all.

For example:

```
preg_match_all('#\<p>(.+?)\<\/p>#s', $html, $matches);
```

Obviously you might want to modify the pattern to suit your needs